# Stamp Annotation added at wrong place

Tags: java, pdfbox

Using below code when we add Stamp Annotation on PDF page, it will add that stamp at random location for some files.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = getImage();
PDImageXObject image = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(pdDocument, bufferedImage)
PDAnnotationRubberStamp rubberStamp = new PDAnnotationRubberStamp();
rubberStamp.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(x, y,  width, height));
rubberStamp.setName(Name);
PDFormXObject form = new PDFormXObject(pdDocument);
form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotation)));
form.setBBox(new PDRectangle(x, y,  width, height));
form.setResources(new PDResources());
PDAppearanceStream myDic = new PDAppearanceStream(form.getCOSObject());
PDPageContentStream pageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, myDic);
pageContentStream.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
pageContentStream.close();
PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary(new COSDictionary());
appearance.setNormalAppearance(myDic);
rubberStamp.setAppearance(appearance);
annotations.add(rubberStamp);
```

For example, for some files x coordinate 0.0 considers right side of page and for some files it will be bottom.

Comment: (0,0) is bottom left, but some pages may be rotated, or there may be a page crop box that is smaller than the page media box. Maybe share the problem PDF files.

Comment: Hi tilman, thanks for your reply..

As per your suggestion, I've executed method page.setRotation(); and it returns 90. So it seems like page is rotated, So please help me further on this.

Comment: You could try the `setNoRotate()` flag on the PDAnnotation object. However PDFBox itself won't handle this correctly in rendering.